# F0520005:Could not open source file "r_bsp_config.h"

Tags: c, mcu, renesas-rx

i'm working with renesas MCU RX65N, i want to make a serial connection with other board and also display an HMI i designed on Appwizard, i followed the steps they offer on their manuals but won't work either. Then found more information about how to solve it, and the code works by itself, but when i try to merge both programs just keeps giving me errors (problems that doesn't appear on individual projects), this is the error i got now, and don't know what to do because apparently it is included for my project but won't open no matter what i try, anyone knows how to solve it or what to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You must tell your compiler where to look for include files. You must provide the path to your include folder where that file is located. As you do not provide any information what you did, we cannot tell you what you are missing. You may check the project setting for the project where you used that file without problems and see what options were used.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that right away

Comment: I checked and apparently the path is added but still nothing, also compared with the program that runs normally and still nothing. I'm using e2 Studio 2021-10

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you include the file in one project, it works, but when you include it in another project, it doesn't? It sounds like there is a configuration difference between your projects. Try creating a new file in a project, then just put `#include "r_bsp_config.h"` in it, or however you wrote it (it may need to be `#include <r_bsp_config.h>`). See if you get the same error (you will probably get an error, something about missing `main()`, but the question is whether you get the same error). If you don't, cut and paste the code from the problematic project in, and also make sure the project configuration is adjusted to match, and see if it works now. If you do get the same error, then see if you can copy the project configuration from the working project to the new project, and see if you get the error this time.